# How can I avoid misuse of a constructor with multiple parameters of the same type?

Tags: java, types, constructor

Should I avoid constructors like this?

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Because they can be misused:

```
Person person = new Person("Smith", "John");
```

And if so, what should I do instead?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with constructors like this. those using them should be able to read either the documentation.

Comment: yes, you can use the above constructor as far as the naming convention is good. Here you have used firstName and lastName which is self-explained.

Comment: Even if you made 2 setters instead, people could still use `setFirstName("Smith")`, so no nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Stultuske If the constructor is more critical (for example by having several IDs passed to it which cannot be mixed up), then you would want the compiler to stop people from misusing it, rather than to trust them to read the documentation correctly.

Comment: @marstran even then there's no problem with such constructors. Normally, the ide gives the param names when you try to fill them in. If not, you can always go for a builder pattern

Comment: @Stultuske Even if the IDE shows what the parameter names are, you could pass the wrong argument to the wrong parameter. I've seen people get stuff like this wrong many times. It's not fool proof when the compiler doesn't give you an error. Now, I'm not saying a constructor like this is bad. Just saying that if your system requires it, you could use types to get stronger guarantees.

Comment: What about [Henry James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_James)? Should that be [James Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Henry_(footballer,_born_1989))? How do you determine what a valid `firstName` is and what a valid `lastName` is?

Comment: @marstran How would you use types to make compiler differentiate multiple IDs that are all of type `int`? How would you use types to make compiler differentiate multiple names that are all of type `String`? Your comment makes no sense, since you suggest making the compiler enforce different types on values that are all of the same type.

Comment: @Andreas Check my answer below. Of course at some point you would need to pass a string or int to a value class, but in the rest of your program you will reap the benefits of the added type safety. Usually my values comes from some JSON which I parse with Jackson, and Jackson is able to parse values directly into my value classes. This means that I don't even have to call the constructor of my value classes manually.

Comment: @marstran So if you're not calling the constructor anyway, the entire point of this question about incorrectly calling the `Person(String firstName, String lastName)` constructor becomes moot, since the JSON parser won't get them mixed up either.

Comment: @Andreas I never said I never call any constructors. Let's say you get firstname and lastname from some other class, for example `User`. Then you could go `new Person(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName);` and you will not be able to mix them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor with multiple fields of the same type is a valid implementation.
If you want to avoid misused issues you can use a builder pattern instead.

```
Person person = Person.builder().firstName("John").lastName("Smith").build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use builder, and [`Lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) project can simplify code

```java
@Builder
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String  lastName;
}
```

Usage is

```java
Person.builder()
    .firstName("John")
    .lastName("Smith")
    .build();
```

Comment: It might help, but one can still put the firstName value in the lastName field.

Comment: Ok, if you want this, you should define classes `class FirstName { private final String value; }` and `class LastName { ... }`. Do you need an example?

Answer (score 1):

Using the builder-pattern will help, but if you really want to avoid misuse, you should make `firstName` and `lastName` typed using value classes.

Proper value classes with no overhead will come in a later Java version, but you could use records if you're on Java 14 (preview feature) or later. It's a bit more cumbersome to make value classes on lower Java versions (you need to create a class with 1 property).

```
record FirstName(String firstName) {}
record LastName(String lastName) {}
```

Now you can do this in your constructor:

```
public Person(FirstName firstName, LastName lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

With this, your example where you switched `"John"` and `"Smith"` would no longer compile.

I often use this pattern when I have a lot of ID-fields I need to pass around. The consequence of mixing them up would be greater.

Another nice side effect of doing this is that your IDE (at least IntelliJ) will have more type-information to suggest auto-completion of your code. Using value classes could therefore speed up your coding a little bit :)

Comment: How would the compiler help prevent switching `"John"` and `"Smith"`? Idiot programmers can still do `Firstname("Smith")` and `Lastname("John")`. I'd say using a builder pattern would be far better than wrapping all simple types in a named value type.

Comment: It's not either types or builder pattern. I usually use both. Also, I usually don't do this when the fields are simple text-fields, but when they are IDs that I need to be more careful with, then I do it.

Comment: Of course you can still do `Firstname("Smith")` and `Lastname("John")`, but then you have taken an active choice to do it. It's more cumbersome to do the wrong thing.